# How to only email report with data, not when empty - Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am not the designer for these reports, so please bear with me for this question.  Our DBA has set up an automated email with an Excel attachment for the results based on a SQL query that I wrote.  The email is sent everyday, regardless of whether or not it has data in it.  I would like the report only to be email if there is data in the report.  Is there a setting for this criteria in Report Builder 3.0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not to answer, but I never liked an option to not send a scheduled report.  A missing email now can mean too many things, did the report run, was it just empty, is there a problem w/ email.  Instead a spreadsheet explicitly stating no data tells the end user that more things worked correctly.

Comment: That is a good point.  However, this is a request from my boss, so you know how that goes :)

Comment: Boo HISS, silly boss requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the size of the excel doc and filter it on the email server and delete it automatically from the emails. I mean, the real report's size should be totally different.

Comment: If you're thinking about yourself you just can add a filter rule to your outlook client. If you are trying to fix all the user's inbox you should do it on the server side.